# Data not rendered in image tag in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

Here I am trying to show image from data object in vue js. Here is my code

```
<a onclick="openModal()"><img src="{{product.productImageList[0]['name']}}"></a>
```

But it shows in dom like

```
<img src="{{product.productImageList[0]['name']}}">
```

Besides if I keep {{product.productImageList[0]['name']}} outside image tag then it shows value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the interpolation

```
<img v-bind:src="product.productImageList[0]['name']">
```

For concatenation either go with

```
<img v-bind:src="'https ://admin.com/item_image/'+product.productImageList[0]['name']">
```

Or use computed property

```
computed: {
getUrl() {
 return url=> {
  const newUrl = `https ://admin.com/item_image/${product.productImageList[0].name}`;
return newUrl;
 }
}
}
```

along with below template change

```
<img v-bind:src="getUrl(product.productImageList[0].name)">
```

Comment: Thanks but **getUrl()** is it ok? no parameter needed

Comment: It's ok . .in the template call only u need to send parameter.

Comment: That's the magic of passing argument in computed

Answer (score 0):

`{{}}` is a template for displaying text. For attribute, instead you use `v-bind` with a valid javascript expression. Change to the following should work:

```
<img v-bind:src="product.productImageList[0]['name']">
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I concatenate path **https ://admin.com/item_image/product.productImageList[0]['name']**

Answer (score 0):

Since the argument is a variable try binding the input like below

```
<img :src="product.productImageList[0]['name']">
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I concatenate path **https ://admin.com/item_image/product.productImageList[0]['name']**